# Vue.js: How to call a method when there is a change inside child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How do I get an action on a child component to trigger a method in the parent component.
As per my example. I have inserted a `b-country-select` component into the parent component and I would like it to fire the `test` method when there is a change. The component loads but nothing happens when I make a change. The `tester2` model works.

Component: BCountrySelect.vue

```
<template>
    <select class="form-control v-model="country">
          <option v-for='data in countries' :value='data.id'>{{ data.name }}</option>
    </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
      return {
          country: 0,
          countries: [{"id":1, "name":"USA"}, {"id":2, "name":"UK"} ]
      }
  },
  methods:{
      getCountries: function(){

        axios.get('/api/getCountries')
        .then(function (response) {
            this.countries = [{"id":0,"name":"- Select Country -"}].concat(response.data);
        }.bind(this));

      },
    },
    created: function(){
     // this.getCountries()
    }
  }
</script>
```

Parent::

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Country:</label>
            <b-country-select v-model="tester1" @change="test()"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Country:</label>
            <select class='form-control' v-model="tester2" @change="test1()">
             <option v-for='data in countries' :value='data.id'>{{ data.name }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
        data(){
            return {
                tester1: 0,
                tester2: 0,
                countries: [{"id":1, "name":"USA"}, {"id":2, "name":"UK"} ]
            }
        },
        methods:{
            test: function() {
                console.log('hi there!');
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Emit  a change event as follows :

```
<select class="form-control v-model="country" @change="$emit('change',country)">
```

in parent :

```
<b-country-select v-model="tester1" @change="test"/>

....

  test: function(country) {
                console.log('hi there! ', country);
            }
```